# Closing DataSource and Using Cursor

Tags: android, database

I have a method which essentially does the following:

```
Cursor cursor;                                  
cursor = myCard.queryRandomCard(this);              
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Within the queryRandomCard method:

```
DataSource datasource = new DataSource(context);
datasource.open();
Cursor cursor  = (SQL STATEMENT IS HERE AND WORKS); 
datasource.close();
return cursor;
```

The problem lay in that, upon retutn I get an error while executing "cursor.moveToFirst()" which says "the connection pool has been closed". HOWEVER, if I remove the "datasource.close()" call, then it works fine.

My question is, why does closing the database here affect the cursor that is returned? Are these two tied together closer than I had realized?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **Cursor** is nothing more than an **iterator** that operates on the tables of Database. With a Cursor you don't load the whole table at once, but you load one row each time you need it, so you need an open connection to the database in order that works.

Comment: well there you go. I thought it returned the entire set. This would then also mean that as long as you are using the same cursor that you must have the same DataSource object as well, right?

Comment: Right the Cursor is bound to the DataSource object that created it. The Cursor uses the DataSource object to get the Database information and get results.